# How to adapt layouts to soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Android app where layout elements size and margins are defined in dimens files (e.g, values-hdpi/dimens.xml, value-xhdpi/dimens.xml, etc.). That worked fine on a few devices, however on the first device with soft keyboard (htc), my elements are not aligned as it should be (keyboard is moved up and overlap some elements). I should note that I'm using my custom keyboard. How can I overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way to adjust for the soft keyboard.  In fact there is no automated way to even know that the keyboard is up or not.  The only response you have to it is the soft input mode, which can either resize your app above the keyboard or pan your app to be above your keyboard.

Comment: Currently its obviously resized. I tried all of the android:windowSoftInputMode for my activity, but the result was the same.

Comment: Since you're using a custom keyboard-  do you have onComputeInsets implemented and are you returning accurate values from it?  It's an obscure method, but it can actually cause  issues if you're doing funky stuff with overlays.

Comment: No I don't have that method.

Comment: If you have overlapping issues that may be it-  the insets tell the OS how big your keyboard is

Comment: I'm setting custom keyboard keyHeight from dimens.xml. This works fine e.g, with hard keys (on xxhdpi), but e.g,. when I have soft keys then keyHeight of custom keyboard should be smaller. How can I set this ?